# oauth2callback.php uri misdirect error

Tags: google-analytics, callback, oauth-2.0

I am trying to do the Hello analytics php quick start https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php#enable.

I have these redirects uris added to the google console developer
http://example.info/index.php
http://example.info/oauth2callback.php
I have the example code set up as following

```
index.php
        <?php
    // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

    // Start a session to persist credentials.
    //session_start();

    // Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
    // from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

    // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
    // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
      // Set the access token on the client.
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

      // Create an authorized analytics service object.
      $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

      // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
      $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

      // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
      $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
      printResults($results);
    } else {
      $redirect_uri = 'http://example.info/oauth2callback.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }


    function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
      // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

      // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
      $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

      if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $properties->getItems();
          $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

          // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
          $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
              ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

          if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $profiles->getItems();

            // Return the first view (profile) ID.
            return $items[0]->getId();

          } else {
            throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
      }
    }

    function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
      // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
      // for the last seven days.
      return $analytics->data_ga->get(
          'ga:' . $profileId,
          '7daysAgo',
          'today',
          'ga:sessions');
    }

    function printResults(&$results) {
      // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
      // the profile name and total sessions.
      if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
        print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
      } else {
        print "<p>No results found.</p>";
      }
    }




 oauth2callback.php
    <?php
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');



    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://example.info/index.php');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $redirect_uri = 'http://example.info/index.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
```

I get error 400 the redirect URI in the request, http://example.info/index.php, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client, even though I am sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing prety much same problem. What happened in my case was that I had many different services configured and since the api services user experience is very bad, I was setting up the call back url for another project.

So, Its a quick try..just copy and past the link in the error screen google shows you:

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch